# 'orderby' in linq using a string array c#

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a method definition as such:

```
public CustomerOrderData[] GetCustomerOrderData(string[] CustomerIDs)
{
 var query = (from a in db.Customer
              join b in db.Order on a.CustomerID equals v.CustomerID
              orderby CustomerIDs
              select new CustomerOrderData()
              {
                //populate props here
              }).ToArray();
}
```

My CustomerIDs in input param could be {"1","3","400","200"}

I want my return array to be ordered in the above fashion. Is there an easy way to achive this?

My solution was to put it into a Dictionary and then create a new array while looping through my CustomerIDs collection.

CustomerOrderData does have a property named CustomerID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you materialize the query, you should be able to find the index of the id in your array and use it as the ordering parameter.  Shown below using extension methods.

```
var ordering = CustomerIDs.ToList();
var query = db.Customer.Join( db.Order, (a,b) => a.CustomerID == b.CustomerID )
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .OrderBy( j => ordering.IndexOf( j.Customer.CustomerID ) )
                       .Select( j => new CustomerOrderData {
                          // do selection
                        })
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: tvanfosson: I tried your method, the returned array does not appear to be sroted by my CustomerIDs string[]. Seems that data is sorted in descending order

Comment: Is customerID a string in the entity class?  If not, try doing an IndexOf( j.Customer.CustomerID.ToString() ) -- or change your array to an array of int values (assuming that's the type on the entity).

Answer (score 5):

I think this solves problem:

`var orderedArray = YourCustomArray.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();`

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't encourage code only answers, especially ones this late after the question was asked. Please add some commentary explaining your code.

Answer (score 4):

if the customerIds always will be numbers then cast it and order it before using it into ur query

```
var orderedIds =  CustomerIDs.Cast<int>().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `IndexOf`:

```cs
orderby ContactIds.IndexOf(a.CustomerId)
```

Note that this might not be efficient for large sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a structure to lookup the desired index using the customerid.

```
string[] CustomerIDs;

Dictionary<string, int> customerIDOrdering = CustomerIds
  .Select((c, i) => new (id = c.CustomerID, i = i})
  .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.i);

var query = from c in ...
    orderby customerIDOrdering[c.CustomerID]  
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The join clause preserves the order of the outer sequence:

"The Join operator preserves the order of the outer sequence elements, and for each outer element, the order of the matching inner sequence elements."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx

So you should not need to orderby at all:

```
from orderIndex in CustomerIDs
join a in db.Customer on orderIndex equals a.CustomerID
join b in db.Order on a.CustomerID equals v.CustomerID
```