# Sort Char without using Array.Sort() - VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I was practicing to code anagram, but I find it easy since there is this method called Array.Sort().

Without using the method above, how do you sort them alphabetically? I just switched from Java to VB.net and still learning so yea :)

Assume this is the code:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim str1, str2, str3 As String
    Dim char1(), char2(), char3() As Char

    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st string:")
    str1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower.Replace(" ", "")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st string:")
    str2 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower.Replace(" ", "")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st string:")
    str3 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower.Replace(" ", "")

    char1 = str1.ToCharArray()
    char2 = str2.ToCharArray()
    char3 = str3.ToCharArray()
End Sub End Module
```

Comment: Are you asking how to code a sort algorithm in VB.NET, instead of using one of the built in sorting methods?  If so, which algorithm, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried doing a nested for loop for every character in char1 and char2, then see if they if char2(i) has values of char1(x). It's pretty complicated to be honest even I is getting confused on my codes :P

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `Linq`, you can call the `OrderBy()` extension on an array.
Here's some examples in C#.

[sort string array using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951687/sort-string-array-using-linq)

['orderby' in linq using a string array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283336/orderby-in-linq-using-a-string-array-c-sharp)

You might do something like this:

```
Dim ordered As Char() = char1.OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToArray()
```